# Dynamically put checkboxes on form

Tags: database, delphi, checkbox, components

I have a table in DB with information about some goods. Goods may be fillable, so we can add text to it. So I want to dynamically generate a list of checkboxes related to info in table and even some checkboxes must be with TEdit component to make a possibility to add text to this item. So how can I do it? What component should I use? I figure out that TTreeView is almost enough, but it doesn't allow to "draw" TEdit near checkboxes. I'm using Delphi 2010. Thanks in advance! Hope for your help!

Comment: `Edit := TEdit.Create(Self); Edit.Parent := Self; Edit.Top := NextTop; inc(NextTop, Spacing);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you would like to create some controls on a form based on the contents of table. In the following example I have assumed you want to do this based on the contents of the current record in a TDBGrid, so you'll have to adapt as needed.

The example assumes a form with a TDBGrid and a TPanel (Panel1) that will hold the controls created at run time.

The TDBGrid will be connected to a TDataSource component and that will be connected to some TDataSet descendant for the table/query with the information. The TDataSource has a OnDataChanged event. This event gets triggered when the data in a field changes or when the current record in the dataset changes. So you can use that to change the controls as the current record changes.

```
procedure TForm1.DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
var
  i: Integer;
  Chk: TCheckBox;
  Edit: TEdit;
begin
  // When the Field is assigned, the call is the result of a change in the field.
  // When the Field is unassigned, the call is the result of changing the current record.
  if Assigned(Field) then
    Exit;

  // Remove controls on panel
  for i := Panel1.ControlCount - 1 downto 0 do
    Panel1.Controls[i].Free;

  // Add controls on panel for current record
  if True then      // Replace this with condition based on contents of current record (if any!)
  begin
    Chk := TCheckBox.Create(Self);  // Set Owner, so it is freed when form is closed.
    Chk.Parent := Panel1;           // Set Parent, so the control is shown.
    Chk.Left := FLeftIndent;        // Create FLeftIndent as a member field of the form, set value in OnCreate.
    Chk.Top := FNextTop;            // Create FNextTop as a member field of the form.
    Inc(FNextTop, FSpacing);        // Create FSpacing as a member field of the form, set value in OnCreate.

    if True then    // Replace this with condition that dictates creation of Edit
    begin
      Edit := TEdit.Create(Self);
      Edit.Parent := Panel1;
      Edit.Left := Chk.Left + Chk.Width + FSpacing;
      Edit.Top := Chk.Top;          // Add offset as needed for proper alignment of CheckBox and Edit.
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Please note that if you do not have any other checkboxes or edits on the form, you will have to include the proper vcl units yourself. The easiest way to do that is to drop them on the form, save the form and then delete the controls again.

Comment: +1 There would presumably need to be some way of identifying the dynamically created edit boxes with the DB fields so that code could respond to user changes in the edit boxes.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, Marjan! The way you offer is the way I thought to implement at the start. I thought that there is much easier way, but you confirm that way. Thanks again!

Comment: What could be easier than having Marjan write it FOR you! [wink].  Nice work Marjan. I suggest setting the Chk.Tag in each object so that the checkbox objects can be associated with something, either as an index (0,1,2,...n) or as a pointer-stored-as-an-integer (which would probably break when you move to win64).

Comment: @Warren: That's one way of doing it and I have done so many times. Nowadays I tend to create a "link-list" (not a linked list) where I link two (or more) pointers or indices. Could be a TStringList (name, value and object!) or just two TList's or TObjectList's that are kept sync'ed on indices. But perhaps that really is only important when writing components or other re-usable GUI stuff where the (CheckBox') Tag may already be used for something else. Yes 64bit is something to consider, though I think they may "up" the Tag to a Pointer size because of all the uses the Tag has been put to.

Answer (score 1):

try [this](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0201_5.htm) example about creating checkbox on runtimehpe it helps you will have to modify the position dynamically. you can either create a new component wich includes checkbox with Edit on it or create the TEdit dynamically where you need it.

Consider creating an array of TCheckbox and one of TEdit and set the visible property of each Edit using something like IsEditNeeded boolean function in which you code the conditions if an Edit field is needed.

Comment: While a good resource, the example you linked is about adding a checkbox to a standard windows dialog. Not sure, from the question, but I'd guess that kseen just wants to create controls at run-time on his/her own form.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to use a gridview like ExGridView, and let it draw my checkboxes, and do the "edit" controls for each row, for me.  However, if you really want an edit box, instead of a grid, you could also try a control-grid approach (1 checkbox + 1 edit control, in a control-grid).